# Should each CRM application have its own instance?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I'm messing with a small CRM application, and I'm a little confused about how to manage customizations that I make. Lets say I customize one of the existing entities (e.g. Appointment) in a solution. When I publish, those changes are moved to the instance and directly affect other small apps that are part of the instance. If those other apps also use the Appointment entity, then things get bloated and complicated. I can't find much guidance on how customizations like this are supposed to be managed. Should each application be isolated in its own instance?

I'm using on-premise CRM by the way. Thanks for any information/guidance.

Comment: When you say "other small apps" do you mean other solutions that also contain the appointment entity?

Comment: Zach - yes, exactly. Or solutions that make use of the Appointment entity (even in its vanilla form)

Comment: Define what "CRM application" and "other small apps" are.  CRM is first a Customer Relationship Management platform, but secondly a rapid application development platform.  If you're not using the CRM functionality, you need to provide much greater detail when it comes to what you are attempting to do with it.

Comment: Daryl - in this case I am using CRM functionality, but I have 2 or 3 solutions that customize the out-of-box entities (e.g. Appointment or Case). See the comments in Zach's answer for some additional details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that you need a separate org for every different set of functionality you desire.  The schema for an org is the composite of all solutions installed on that org.  A well designed set of solutions will have a hierarchy where some solutions build off others and in some cases you may have solutions that have no overlapping functionality but all of them work together to form the schema for the org they are installed on.

Comment: So is it common practice to run multiple CRM instances/orgs like this? And is there a way to handle synchronizing common data such as user accounts or sites between orgs? I see mention of "master data management" here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn722373%28v=crm.6%29.aspx

Comment: I would need more information about why you need separate sets of functionality.  Do you have multiple sets of users who need to view and work with the same data in different ways?  This can probably be achieved through a single org and set of solutions by building different forms/views/processes for different user types.

Comment: I'm guess I'm just trying to get a feel for what most companies do. Typically applications have their own databases, which makes me feel uneasy about having the Appointment entity contain app-specific fields or reference a custom app-specific entity if it's being shared between many apps. Are role-based forms the best way to handle these custom fields? What if I want a field to be required for one app only and logically not exist in others? The only shared data we would have is user accounts I believe.

Comment: I think I am starting to understand your situation a bit better and your question is not trivial.  It is certainly possible to design a single dynamics CRM org to store data for many disparate applications.  How this is designed of course depends on the details of your applications and what they have in common (user data for instance).

Comment: If you decide to go this route you could go with a two layer approach. The bottom layer would be a single solution that contains all elements that are common across the various applications.  The top layer would build upon the bottom layer and have many solutions, each one containing tables and fields specific to a single application.